# facet_wrap in shiny app

Tags: r, csv, ggplot2, shiny

I'm new to `shiny`. I want to make a `shiny` app that enables the user to upload a csv file then plot the data.

You can download [**the data from here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3q2eayogbe0bgl/shiny_data.csv?dl=0).

I made it as below

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
#ui.R
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("My shiny app"), sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  helpText("Blah blah blah"),
  a("Data to be plotted", href="https://www.dropbox.com/s/t3q2eayogbe0bgl/shiny_data.csv?dl=0"),
  tags$hr(),
  fileInput("file","Upload the file"), 
  h5(helpText("Select the read.table parameters below")),
  checkboxInput(inputId = 'header', label = 'Header', value = TRUE),
  checkboxInput(inputId = "stringAsFactors", "stringAsFactors", FALSE),
  br(),
  radioButtons(inputId = 'sep', label = 'Separator', choices = c(Comma=',',Semicolon=';',Tab='\t', Space=''), selected = ',')
),
mainPanel(
  uiOutput("tb"),
  plotOutput("line")             
)
)
)

#server.R
server <- function(input,output){
data <- reactive({


file1 <- input$file
if(is.null(file1)){return()} 

read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)})

output$filedf <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
input$file
}) 

output$sum <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
summary(data())
})

output$table <- renderTable({
if(is.null(data())){return ()}
data()
})

output$line <- renderPlot({
if (is.null(data())) { return() }
print(ggplot(data(), aes(x=date, y=aa)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~station)) })

output$tb <- renderUI({if(is.null(data()))
h5()               
else
  tabsetPanel(tabPanel("About file", tableOutput("filedf")),tabPanel("Data", tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("Summary", tableOutput("sum")))
})
}


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The app partially worked. I can upload a csv file but the plot appears empty when I use `facet_wrap`. Any suggestion how to get the plot after uploading the data for the three stations would be appreciated.

Comment: you just need to format you column date as a Date (instead of a character)

Comment: @MLavoie
Thanks. I tried formatting date as Date inside data <- reactive({ })
as follows 
df.raw <- read.table(file=file1$datapath, sep=input$sep, header = input$header, stringsAsFactors = input$stringAsFactors)
df.raw$date <- as.Date(df.raw$date, format="%d/%m/%Y") 
but it didn't work. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set your date inside your renderPlot() expression. Is it what you want?

```
output$line <- renderPlot({
if (is.null(data())) { return() }

df <- data()
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, format="%d/%m/%Y") 

print(ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=aa)) + geom_line()+ facet_wrap(~station)) })
```

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. I was formatting the date in the wrong place. Thanks again :-)